# C# SerialPort.ReadLine difference to terminal serial read

Tags: c#, serial-port

What are the differences between this C# code running inside Unity:

```
    SerialPort stream = new SerialPort ( "/dev/cu.usbserial-A9Y59ZJV", 9600 );
    stream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
    stream.Open();

    while( stream.IsOpen )
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Log( stream.ReadLine() );
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError (name + " timed out reading from Arduino: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

and running the Unix terminal command:

```
screen /dev/cu.usbserial-A9Y59ZJV 9600 –L
```

The C# Code throws TimeoutExceptions.
The Terminal command reads data (it comes in ever second)

The two are not ran at the same time.  The unity code is in reality split into Start() and Update() messages properly.

Answer (score 1):

I realised my mistake while writing the question, but am answering incase someone else has the same problem.

Be careful with the difference between "\r\n" and "\n".  C#s SerialPort [expects different values depending on platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're sending data without the receiving platforms version of a newline, you cannot use [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).  Use [ReadByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: line feeds have always been out to get us

Comment: You can actually set the new line delimiter you want in the `NewLine` property. But I've had some issues with it in the past, don't remember exactly what the issues were. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Change the SerialPort.NewLine property or use ReadTo().